# Show hidden div based of any value contained in the input field in modal form

Tags: jquery, html

Ive spent the last 4 hours searching Google and SO for the answer to this.  The answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837704/show-hidden-div-based-of-any-value-contained-in-the-input-field) was the closest I could find to what I am looking for, but in my case the `<div class="fhlbinfo">` are not showing or hiding based on the value of the input field in `<div class="fhlbyes">` when the modal form loads so I am obviously missing something.  I have checked for typos and havent found any.

```
<div class="form-group">

  <div class="fhlbyes">
    <label>FHLB Loan</label>

    <input style="background-color: RGB(208,206,206)" type="text" name="fhlbloan" placeholder="Yes/No" value="<?php echo $fetch['fhlbloan'];?>" class="form-control" />
  </div>

</div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
  $(function() {
    if ($(".fhlbyes input[value == 'Yes']")) {
      $('.fhlbinfo').show();
    } else {
      $('.fhlbinfo').hide();
    }
  })
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="fhlbinfo" style="display: none">

    <label>Keyed on Servicing Module</label>

    <input type="text" name="srvcmodule" placeholder="Yes/No" value="<?php echo $fetch['srvcmodule'];?>" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you set `display:none` if your input's natural state is "Yes" ?

Comment: @Nyx  That was left over from when i copied the code from a different file.  I have tried removing that and it makes no difference.  The inputs natural state isnt "Yes"  it could be "Yes", "No" or NULL.

Comment: Would you check if my answer below helps you or I misunderstood your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, the change never happens because you don't tell the code when to execute this function, so I added a keyup event listener to change fhlbinfo's display property as soon as it notices the required input value (Yes)

I also believe that it won't happen on DOM load because you've exclusively said that you want fhlbinfo's natural state to be hidden no matter of your input's value and the only way to change this is by re-setting the input's value inside the script.

There are two ways I can think of right now...

Either you remove `display:none` and you keep the default value to "Yes" in which case the natural state of fhlbinfo is not hidden and  it matches the default value.

Either you remove the default value "Yes" and keep the `disply:none` attribute for the fhlbinfo div in which case the default state of fhlbinfo is hidden and matches the input's value (other than yes)

Both of this ways help you to have fhlbinfo's state aligned with the input's default value on DOM load and when it comes to future changes (after DOM is loaded) the keyup event listener will listen for changes and set fhlbinfo's state according to the conditional statement specified inside it's function (show when input's value = Yes in your case)

**I RECOMMEND USING THE SECOND WAY BECAUSE YOU MAKE USE OF THE PLACEHOLDER**

in both cases use the JS code below

```js
$(".fhlbyes input").ready(function() {
  if ($(".fhlbyes input").val() == 'Yes') {
    $('.fhlbinfo').show();
  } else {
    $('.fhlbinfo').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <div class="fhlbyes">
    <label>FHLB Loan</label>

    <input style="background-color: RGB(208,206,206)" type="text" name="fhlbloan" placeholder="Yes/No" value="Yes" class="form-control" />
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="fhlbinfo">

    <label>Keyed on Servicing Module</label>

    <input type="text" name="srvcmodule" placeholder="Yes/No" value="Your value>" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like its going to be calling the function when a change is made to the `fhlbyes` input field which wont be changed.  I just need it to show the `fhlbinfo` containers when the modal window loads and the value of the input field is "Yes".

Comment: Is there a case scenario when the value of the input is "No" on load?

Comment: Yes.  The value on load could be Yes, No, or a NULL value

Comment: Try it now, see if it matches your requirements

Comment: Still didn't work as expected.  Maybe I just need to look at the value stored in the database instead of the actual field in the modal form?

Comment: You can try it that way but I think it will take up writing too much code that can be avoided, you came up with quite a minimal way to do this, we just need to make it work, anyway, from what I can see, right now it loads accordingly (if yes, the second input is shown if anything else the second field is hidden) Can you try to explain precisely what you expect and how this last updated version is not matching your expectations right now?

Comment: sorry for the delay as ive been sick.  The logic for what you wrote should work and I'm not sure why it doesn't hide anything with the class of fhlbinfo.  Could the placeholder be throwing off the function?

Comment: Nope, the function is tied to its value, if yes - show, anything else - hide, but I found it weird not working since it works fine in the snippet, try checking for any error messages or clear the browser's history (cache files) because sometimes you may update the code but the browser be still reading the cached file (you can check if this is the case with inspect element), also console.log fhlbyes's value just to make sure it results in the way you want (a clean Yes) because sometimes when retrieving data you may have the PHP written wrong and it may be returning .Yes. or 'Yes'

Comment: Make sure to tell me if you find out what was causing the problem, I am curious to know

Comment: I cleared the browser cache and that didnt help.  The console.log returned a value of "Yes"

Comment: Did it returned Yes or "Yes" ... I mean, are you using the quotes to quote what console.log returned or console.log literally returned quoted yes ("Yes")? @ZackE

Comment: console.log literally returned "Yes"

Comment: Okay, so that is what is causing the problem, the script says if the value of the first input equals Yes then show the second input if anything else then hide the second input and since (Yes does not equal "Yes") your input's value will always hide the second input, so what you want to do here is retrieve a clean Yes and you do that by properly adjusting the code around the first input's value, I assume your code looks something like this `<input name="fhlbloan" value="<?php echo ".$value." ?>"` try playing around with it or show me how your <input> line looks like and I will adjust it for you

Comment: Ideally it should look like this `<input name="fhlbloan" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">` so `value="<?php echo $value; ?>"` is the crucial part and currently the way you retrieve your first input's value is what is causing the problem, remember the script expects a clean Yes and anything else will not show the second input. If you are pulling the value directly from the table like this `<input value="<?php ".$row['value']."?>">` then your best solution is to place the value in a variable `$value = $row['value']` and then you can just echo $value without overthinking the logic behind the quotes

Comment: Here is what my input line looks like `<input style="background-color: RGB(208,206,206)" type="text" name="fhlbloan" value="<?php echo $fetch['fhlbloan'];?>"`

Comment: Okay so I've tried your code and it seems to be working perfectly fine returning the exact same value that is stored into the database leaving only one possible option and that is if the value in the database is "Yes", now first you will need to check your database and see if the values stored in the database are actually quoted and if they are, you have two options, you either tell the script to show the second input if the value of the first input equals "Yes" (quoted Yes) or you can change the code that inputs in the database and make sure it inputs clean Yes instead of quoted Yes ("Yes")

Comment: Either way, the values in the database have to be quoted, there is no other possible explanation that will output a quoted Yes (using this code) that I can think of right now and If they are not quoted inside the database itself, then your entire code needs to be reviewed

Comment: I am going to have rethink how this is coded.  Thank you very much for the insights.  After the code is reworked if i run into any issues I will post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Use only simple `=` instead of `==` to compare the value attribute of your input field. Then check how many matching DOM elements are found.

Further, it's not recommended to include a javascript file and within the same tag write your personal javascript code (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <div class="fhlbyes">
    <label>FHLB Loan</label>

    <input style="background-color: RGB(208,206,206)" type="text" name="fhlbloan" placeholder="Yes/No" value="Yes" class="form-control" />
  </div>

</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    if ($(".fhlbyes input[value='Yes']").length > 0) {
      $('.fhlbinfo').show();
    } else {
      $('.fhlbinfo').hide();
    }
  })
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="fhlbinfo" style="display: none">

    <label>Keyed on Servicing Module</label>

    <input type="text" name="srvcmodule" placeholder="Yes/No" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt work as the fields are still visible when  `if ($(".fhlbyes input[value='Yes']"))` returns false.  Thank you for the advice on placement of the source script.

Comment: I adapted the condition to work properly. Maybe that will solve you problem. Otherwise let me know